# How to turn off events.out.tfevents file in tf.contrib.learn Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

When using **estimator.Estimator** in **tensorflow.contrib.learn,** after training and prediction there are these files in the **modeldir**:

- checkpoint
- events.out.tfevents.1487956647
- events.out.tfevents.1487957016
- graph.pbtxt
- model.ckpt-101.data-00000-of-00001
- model.ckpt-101.index
- model.ckpt-101.meta

When the graph is complicated or the number of variables is big, the graph.pbtxt file and the events files can be very big. Is here a way to not write these files? Since model reloading only needs the checkpoint files removing them won't affect evaluation and prediction down the road.

Comment: One workaround is to reduce checkpoint frequency.

Answer (score 2):

On [Google's Machine Learning Crash Course](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/) they use the following approach:

```py
# Create classifier:
classifier = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    optimizer=optimizer
)

# Train it:
classifier.train(
    input_fn=training_input_fn,
    steps=steps
)

# Remove event files to save disk space.
_ = map(os.remove, glob.glob(os.path.join(classifier.model_dir, 'events.out.tfevents*')))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the events.out.tfevents files to be written. Find in your code somethings like these and delete them.

```
tfFileWriter = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.getcwd())
tfFileWriter.add_graph(sess.graph)
tfFileWriter.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was not able to find any resolution for this while the events file kept on growing in size. My understanding is that this file stores the events generated by tensorflow. I went ahead and deleted this manually.
Interestingly, it never got created again while the other files are getting updated when I run a train sequence.

Comment: Not a direct answer to this question, but +1 because I was trying to figure out if I can delete this _during_ training -- turns out I can. Thanks!